# Random walk on a 2D grid

Tags: java, beginner, random

The program assignment:

> A drunkard in a grid of streets randomly picks one of four directions
>   and stumbles to the next intersection, then again randomly picks one
>   of four directions, and so on. You might think that on average the
>   drunkard doesn't move very far because the choices cancel each other
>   out, but that is not the case. Represent locations as integer pairs
>   (x,y). Implement the drunkard's walk over 100 intersections, starting
>   at (0,0) and print the ending location.

I created this `Drunkard` class:

```
import java.util.*;

class Drunkard {
    int x, y; 
    Drunkard(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x; 
    this.y = y;
    } 
    void moveNorth() {
    this.y -= 1; 
    }
    void moveSouth() {
    this.y += 1; 
    }
    void moveEast() {
    this.x += 1; 
    }
    void moveWest() {
    this.x -= 1; 
    }
    void report() {
    System.out.println("Location: " + x + ", " + y); 
    } 
}
```

And this `DrunkardTester` class to test the above class

```
import java.util.Random;

public class DrunkardTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random generator = new Random(); 
    Drunkard drunkard = new Drunkard(0, 0); 
    int direction; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        direction = Math.abs(generator.nextInt()) % 4; 
        if        (direction == 0) { // N
        drunkard.moveNorth();
        } else if (direction == 1) { // E
        drunkard.moveEast(); 
        } else if (direction == 2) { // S
        drunkard.moveSouth();
        } else if (direction == 3) { // W
        drunkard.moveWest();
        } else {
        System.out.println("Impossible!"); 
        }      
    } 
    drunkard.report();
    }

}
```

It complies and runs fine, and it prints a different coordinate location each time I run it, but I just wanted to get a few other pairs of eyes on it to see if there are any glaring errors.

Also, on my `DrunkardTester` class is there anyway to eliminate the "Impossible!" `else` statement? I wasn't really sure if that was necessary or what else could be put there.

Comment: Simplify your random call to `generator.nextInt(MAX_DIRECTION)` where MAX_DIRECTION is an int constant and == 4.

Comment: Your code is correct, easy to follow, and neatly formatted. It's standard practice to indent the statements in each of the `if` branches, but you might consider replacing the multi-part `if` with `switch`.

Answer (score 9):

There is absolutely no need to call `Math.abs` for `generator.nextInt()` since nextInt will never produce a negative number. Also, your last else-statement is impossible to happen so you can erase that one.

There is also no need to use the modulo (`%`) operator to fix your `direction` variable to the correct range when you instead can supply an integer value to the `nextInt` method. `generator.nextInt(4);` will give you a value from 0 to 3 (inclusive).

It is a Java coding convention to indent your code properly, after each `{` the next line should have one more indentation step, like this:

```
void moveSouth() {
    this.y += 1; 
}
```

---

The below might be a little bit over your level, but it is a really nice solution and is very useful to learn. When you are dealing with four directions, I would create an `enum` to help with the different direction possibilities.

```
public enum Direction4 {
    NORTH(0, -1), EAST(1, 0), SOUTH(0, 1), WEST(-1, 0);

    private final int dx;
    private final int dy;

    private Direction4(int dx, int dy) {
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;
    }
    public int getX() { return dx; }
    public int getY() { return dy; }
}
```

Using this enum, you can simplify several things of your other code. For starters, you can replace your move-methods with one single move method:

```
void move(Direction4 direction) {
    this.x += direction.getX();
    this.y += direction.getY();
}
```

And when generating the direction to move at, you can use the `Direction4` enum:

```
// Get an index number and input the "size" of the enum to `nextInt`
int directionIndex = generator.nextInt(Direction4.values().length);

// Get the direction from the index generated above
Direction4 dir = Direction4.values()[directionIndex];

// Make the move:
drunkard.move(dir);
```

It might be subjective whether four different `moveNorth`, `moveSouth` etc. methods are preferable instead of using a single `move`-method that takes the direction as an argument. I myself find that using an `enum` redures the amount of code and it makes the code flexible and scalable (if you want to add or modify existing directions you can do so, for example adding `MEGA_NORTH` that moves 10 steps north just for fun).

If you don't perform the `enum` approach, then at least use a `switch`

```
direction = generator.nextInt(4);
switch (direction) {
    case 0:
        drunkard.moveNorth();
        break;
    case 1:
        drunkard.moveEast();
        break;
    case 2:
        drunkard.moveSouth();
        break;
    case 3:
        drunkard.moveWest();
        break;
}
```

Although I must say: There's not much that beat a nice little enum :)

Comment: I would probably add one more abstraction around choosing a direction.  Enum.values() returns an array, so I would want to have an interface with a signature like

<T> T choose(T[] choices);
one of the implementations of which uses an instance of Random to pick from the array.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason I don't see the reason for making it an interface, but it surely could be a static utility method.

Answer (score 3):

First, please **indent** your code.

Your sequence of if-elses would be better as a `switch` — it's more efficient and more readable.  However, in general, a big `switch` statement in Java can usually be replaced with something better.  In this case, an **`enum`** for the four cardinal directions would really help.

```
enum Direction {
    NORTH(0, 1),
    EAST(1, 0),
    SOUTH(0, -1),
    WEST(-1, 0);

    public final int x, y;

    private Direction(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    private static Random generator = new Random();

    public static Direction random() {
        return values()[generator.nextInt(4)];
    }
}
```

Notice the following benefits from using an `enum`:

- No more `switch` statement.
- In the `Drunkard` class, four methods can be replaced with `void move(Direction d)`.
- A lot of code (i.e., machine instructions) has been replaced with data.  Data is usually easier to manage than code.
- The assumption of four cardinal directions is centralized, rather than divided between `Drunkard` and `DrunkardTester`.  If, for example, you wanted to allow diagonal moves, you would only need to modify the `Direction` enum.

> You asked, what to do about the impossible case.  To assert that a situation is impossible, use an **`assert`**.  Alternatively, throw a `RuntimeException`.  Printing a message to `System.out` just clutters the output and lets your faulty program continue, when the right thing to do is to abort.  (By the way, if you must print diagnostics, print to `System.err` instead, to avoid contaminating the output on `System.out`.)

Also note that a more proper way to uniformly pick a number from [0, 1, 2, 3] is `random.nextInt(4)`.  In general, doing `random.nextInt() % n` *might* be slightly biased.  (Consider a hypothetical case where n = 1 billion.  Since `.nextInt()` picks uniformly from integers between 0 and 2 147 483 647, the lowest 147 483 647 numbers are 50% more likely to be picked with `random.nextInt() % 1000000000`.  When n = 4, there happens to be no bias, but you might as well call the right code out of habit.)

A few more tips:

- In `Drunkard`, instead of `void report() { System.out.println(...); }`, **prefer `String toString() { ... }`**.  This gives the caller flexibility to display the result, for example, in a graphical UI.
- In `Drunkard`, also offer a **no-argument constructor** that places the drunkard at the origin.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you indent inner statements?

The constants 0, 1, 2, 3 could be declared as constants like

```
private static final short NORTH = 0;
private static final short EAST = 1;
etc...
```

Also, the "Impossible!" is an unreachable statement so it would be fine to remove it in your case.

Comment: No sure who down-voted this without a comment, but extracting a magic number to a constant is always a good idea. As stated above, a Enum is a better choice here, but if you go with the current approach extracting the constant make your code easier to handle.

Answer (score 2):

It's functional.

**A suggestion:** It's good java practice to only import the classes you need. So I suggest not using the *** notation to import all of the java.util package, actually you don't even use anything from the java.util package so you might as well remove unused imports.

Remove this:

```
import java.util.*;
```