# Tilt maze solution

Tags: java, algorithm, pathfinding

If one does not know tilt maze then the game looks like [this](http://www.mathsisfun.com/games/tilt-maze.html). Basically one can travel in 4 directions North, East, South and West, but this travel's endpoint is the furthest *non-obstructed* block. If solution has multiple routes, then the any single solution is returned which need not be optimal.

Please verify complexity: O(row * col).  I'm looking for code review, good practices, optimizations etc.

```
final class CoordinateTiltMaze {

    private final int row;
    private final int col;

    CoordinateTiltMaze(int row, int col) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public int getCol() {
        return col;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)  return true;
        if (o == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != o.getClass()) return  false;
        final CoordinateTiltMaze coordinateTiltMaze = (CoordinateTiltMaze)o;
        return row == coordinateTiltMaze.row && col == coordinateTiltMaze.col;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return row + col;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return row + " : " + col;
    }
}

public final class TiltMaze {

    private boolean[][] maze;

    static int ctr = 0;

    public TiltMaze(boolean[][] maze) {
        if (maze.length == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The maze should have length.");
        this.maze = maze;
    }

/**
 * 
 * Returns the path from source to destination.
 * If solution has multiple routes, then the any single solution is returned which need not be optimal. Please
 * verify complexity - O (row * col) Looking for code review, good practices, optimizations etc.
 * 
 * 
 * @param startRow
 *            The row index of the start position.
 * @param startCol
 *            The col index of the start position
 * @param endRow
 *            The row index of the end position
 * @param endCol
 *            The column index of end positin
 * @return The path from source to destination, empty set if non exists
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             on invalid input.
 */
    public Set<CoordinateTiltMaze> getPath (int startRow, int startCol, int endRow, int endCol) {
        verify(startRow, startCol, endRow, endCol);
        final Set<CoordinateTiltMaze> coordinateSet = new LinkedHashSet<CoordinateTiltMaze>();
        if (processPoint(startRow, startCol, endRow, endCol, coordinateSet)) return coordinateSet;
        return Collections.EMPTY_SET; 
    }

    private void verify(int startRow, int startCol, int endRow, int endCol) {
        if (rowOutOfBound(startRow)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The startRow: " + startRow + " is out of bounds.");
        if (columnOutOfBound(startCol)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The startCol: " + startCol + " is out of bounds");
        if (rowOutOfBound(endRow)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The endRow: " + endRow + " is out of bounds.");
        if (columnOutOfBound(endCol)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The endCol: " + endCol + " is out of bounds");
    }

    private boolean rowOutOfBound(int startRow) {
       return startRow < 0 || startRow >= maze.length;
    }

    private boolean columnOutOfBound(int startCol) {
        return startCol < 0 || startCol >= maze[0].length;
    }

    private boolean processPoint (int row, int col, int endRow, int endCol, Set<CoordinateTiltMaze> coordinateSet) {
        final CoordinateTiltMaze coord = new CoordinateTiltMaze(row, col);

        if (row == endRow && col == endCol) {
            coordinateSet.add(coord); 
            return true;
        }

        if (coordinateSet.contains(coord)) {
            return false;
        }

        coordinateSet.add(coord);

        for  (CoordinateTiltMaze neighbor : getNeighbors(row, col)) {
            if (processPoint (neighbor.getRow(), neighbor.getCol(), endRow, endCol, coordinateSet)) return true;
        }

        coordinateSet.remove(coord);
        return false;
    }


    private List<CoordinateTiltMaze> getNeighbors(int row, int col) {
        final List<CoordinateTiltMaze> nodes = new ArrayList<CoordinateTiltMaze>();

        // north.
        for (int i = row - 1; i >= -1; i--) {
            if (isObstacle(i, col)) {
                nodes.add(new CoordinateTiltMaze(i + 1, col));
                break;
            }
        }

        // east.
        for (int i = col + 1; i <= maze[0].length; i++) {
            if (isObstacle(row, i)) {
                nodes.add(new CoordinateTiltMaze(row, i - 1));
                break;
            }
        }

        // south
        for (int i = row + 1; i <= maze.length; i++) {
            if (isObstacle(i, col)) {
                nodes.add(new CoordinateTiltMaze(i - 1, col));
                break;
            }
        }

        // west
        for (int i = col - 1; i >= -1; i--) {
            if (isObstacle(row, i)) {
                nodes.add(new CoordinateTiltMaze(row, i + 1));
                break;
            }
        }

        return nodes;
    }


    private boolean isObstacle(int newRow, int newCol) {
        // in bounds of board.
        if (newRow < 0 || newCol < 0 || newRow >= maze.length || newCol >= maze[0].length) {
            return true;
        }

        // 1's in a matrix represent obstacles.
        if (!maze[newRow][newCol]) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean[][] m = { 
                      {true, true, false, false},
                      {true, true, true, true},
                      {true, false, false, true}
                    };

        TiltMaze tiltMaze = new TiltMaze(m);
        for (CoordinateTiltMaze coordTiltMaze : tiltMaze.getPath(0, 0, 2, 3)) {
            System.out.println(coordTiltMaze);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## hashCode implementation

Your `hashCode` method leaves some things to be desired.

The more often a hashCode is unique, the better. Even though your `CoordinateTiltMaze` class fulfills the equals & hashCode contract, your if an object has the hashCode `9` it could mean that it is (5, 4), (4, 5), (3, 6), (1, 8) and so on...

A better implementation would be:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + row;
    result = prime * result + col;
    return result;
}
```

This will make the resulting hashCode a lot more unique. In fact, none of the previous objects that had the same hashCode will now have a unique hashCode. And you will still fulfill the hashCode & equals contract.

*(Hint: Your IDE almost certainly provides a way to automatically generate a good hashCode implementation, I used Eclipse to generate the above one)*

## Code duplication in `getNeighbors`

You have four sets of code in your `getNeighbors` method, one for each direction. I believe that you can get rid of some of this code duplication by using an [Direction4 enum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/34054/random-walk-on-a-2d-grid/34056#34056).

## Naming

Your naming of `CoordinateTiltMaze` was a bit confusing for me for a moment. Is it a Maze for a CoordinateTilt? No! It's a Coordinate for a TiltMaze! I think `TiltMazeCoordinate`, `MazeCoordinate`, or simply `Coordinate` would be a better name. Or even `Point`. Because this class is not coupled to your `TiltMaze` at all, and this is good. It is totally re-usable in all of your projects where you are working with 2d coordinates.