# Agent that steps and turns on a grid

Tags: java, algorithm

The following function uses a cartesian system and has an agent who moves on the table like: F - forward, L - turn left, R - turn right.

The code works fine but I would like to make it more efficient:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
      int x = 0, y = 0;                                 //initial coordinates
      int direction = 0;                                //initial direction
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Introduce the command: ");
    String inputString = scanner.nextLine();            //get the command

    for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++){
        char c = inputString.charAt(i);                 //breaking the string into chars
        if(c == 'l') {                                  //determining the direction
            direction++;
        } else if (c == 'r') {
            direction--;
        } else if (c == 'f') {
            if(direction < 0) {
                direction +=4;
            } 
            if(direction % 4 ==0) {                     //moving forward in the wanted direction
                y++;
            } else if (direction % 4 ==1) {
                x--;
            } else if (direction % 4 == 2) {
                y--;
            } else if(direction % 4 == 3) {
                x++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Result: ["+x+","+y+"]");                
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using two variables — an *x* and a *y* component — to store the direction.  The left and right turns are based on [cross product principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product).

Then, each forward move can be done using unconditional additions with no modulo operations.  An additional advantage is that the meaning of the direction is self-evident.  (It's not immediately obvious what `direction = 1` would mean in your code.)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CartesianAgent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        int dx = 0, dy = 1;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Introduce the command: ");
        String command = scanner.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < command.length(); i++) {
            switch (command.charAt(i)) {
              case 'l':
                int old_dx = dx;
                dx = -dy;
                dy = old_dx;
                break;
              case 'r':
                old_dx = dx;
                dx = dy;
                dy = -old_dx;
                break;
              case 'f':
                x += dx;
                y += dy;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("Result: [%d,%d]%n", x, y);
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, store the direction as a single integer, and use lookup tables to decode it.

According to the convention you chose, `direction = 0` points up (in the +*y* direction), and turns left as `direction` increases (assuming a standard Cartesian grid that follows the right-hand rule).  I consider that to be weird.  You should either use

- `direction = 0` points up, then turns clockwise as `direction` increases (like [navigation headings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heading_%28navigation%29)), or
- `direction = 0` points to the right (in the +*x* direction), then turns counterclockwise as `direction` increases (like [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system)).

The modulo operation should be done when turning, rather than when advancing.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CartesianAgent {
    private static final int[] DX = {  0, +1,  0, -1 },
                               DY = { +1,  0, -1,  0 };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 0, y = 0, direction = 0;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Introduce the command: ");
        String command = scanner.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < command.length(); i++) {
            switch (command.charAt(i)) {
              case 'l':
                direction = (direction + 3) % 4;
                break;
              case 'r':
                direction = (direction + 1) % 4;
                break;
              case 'f':
                x += DX[direction];
                y += DY[direction];
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("Result: [%s,%s]%n", x, y);
    }
}
```

---

Printing the result using `System.out.printf()` is a bit more readable than concatenating the string using `+`.

Comment: To store the direction I would recommend a [Direction enum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/34056/31562) (that can be extended with things like `rotateLeft` and `rotateRight`)